# How to check text in textbox?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a VideoClub application. I have a textbox named `txtMovieDuration`, where I want to type in the movie duration ofc.
What I did is, I allowed the user to write ONLY numbers in this format (hh:mm:ss). The dots appear automatically.
BUT, there is this problem, that logicaly ss (seconds) and mm (minutes) can't be bigger than `59` (cuz they only go from 0 to 59). How can I check seconds and minutes to be `< 60` ?

```
private void txtMovieDuration_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            txtMovieDuration.MaxLength = 8;

            if (txtMovieDuration.Text.Length == 2)
            {
                txtMovieDuration.Text += ":";
            }

            if (txtMovieDuration.Text.Length == 5)
            {
                txtMovieDuration.Text += ":";
            }

            txtMovieDuration.SelectionStart = txtMovieDuration.Text.Length;
         }
```

Comment: You will need to use some kind of regex validations. Or, you can split the string on : and validate each individual part.

Comment: The classic way is try to convert the input into a date or time object. If it fails make an error handling.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a `DateTimePicker` or a `MaskedTextBox`? Doing things like that to a `TextBox` can be buggy if not well-written.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Use the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) control, with it's format property set to Time.

However, if you are stuck using a textBox, you could

- use a regex to check the format (as in @David Aleu's answer)
- split the string on the separator (`:`) and validate the parts manually, like:

  ```
  string[] parts = txtMovieDuration.Text.Split(':');
  if (parts.Length !=3) //there must be a hh:mi:ss parts
  {
     MessageBox.Show("invalid time string");
     return;
  }
  int hours;
  if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out hours))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the hours part is not a number");
     return;
  }
  //if you want to check the value of hours as sensible you could do it here
  //as there are very few movies longer than 10 hours
  int minutes;
  if (int.TryParse(parts[1], out minutes))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the minutes part is not a number");
     return;
  }
  if ((minutes < 0) || (minutes > 59)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the minutes part is out of range");
     return;
  }

  int seconds;
  if (int.TryParse(parts[2], out seconds))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the seconds part is not a number");
     return;
  }
  if ((seconds < 0) || (seconds > 59)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the seconds part is out of range");
     return;
  }
  //you can now make a TimeSpan object for the duration
  TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
  ```

  You could also not check the range of the hours/minutes/seconds variable, but (ab)use a feature of the `TimeSpan` constructor. Since the values are just converted to ticks, and the ticks used to initialize the `TimeSpan`, it's legal to do `new TimeSpan(1000,2000,3000)`. It will create a timespan of 1000 hours, 2000 minutes (a.k.a. 33 hours 20 minutes) and 3000 seconds (aka 50 minutes), resulting in a timespan of 43 days, 2 hours and 10 minutes. This all means that you could do:

  ```
  TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
  if ((duration .Hours != hours)
       || (duration .Minutes != minutes) 
       || (duration .Seconds != seconds))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("the seconds part is out of range");
     return;
  }
  ```

Comment: Also need to set `ShowUpDown` to `True` or else you will see a calendar. There is also a problem that you may not set hour value to > 23

Comment: @AlvinWong, according to [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_movies) that would be a problem only for 10 movies. And I suspect most of those are boring.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx) to validate the user input:

```
TimeSpan duration;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(txtMovieDuration.Text, out duration))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please use correct format 'hh:mm:ss'!)");
}
```

You should consider to use an optional [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) control as [SWeko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14215014/284240) has mentioned.

Comment: Nice way of doing it. Although using this he cannot really tell the user exactly what he did wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

What about if you do this?

```
public bool ValidateTime(string time)
{
     Regex regExp = new Regex(@"(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");

     return regExp.IsMatch(time);
}
```

[Found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b7fa0fa0-3f74-4fe0-b3c8-43ac646da63d)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the string value from the text box and convert it to Int or whatever data type you are using.
More help on converting can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a substring of the seconds.

```
String sub = txtMovieDuration.Text.Substring(6);
if(Convert.ToInt32(sub) < 60)
//Do something here
```

Do the same for minutes or do them together. 
Eg:

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(txtMovieDuration.Text.Substring(3,2)) && Convert.ToInt32(txtMovieDuration.Text.Substring(6)) > 60)
{ 
   //Error handling code

}
```

Note: I am assuming that the : are part of the string. If not, just change the substring start and end values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MaskedTextBox` with the mask as `00:00:00` instead of using a normal `TextBox` which it will automatically add `:`s and only allow inputting numbers.

To check if the value of it is a valid time span value, set its `ValidatingType` to `TimeSpan`.

```
this.maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(TimeSpan);
```

Then you can listen to the `MaskedTextBox.TypeValidationCompleted` event and use `e.IsValidInput` to determine if the user has entered a correct time span value.